# Setting a variable from a text file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have the following:

```
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%a IN (%input%) do (
dsquery * forestroot -filter "(&(mail=%%a))" | dsget user -UPN >> p.txt 2> tmp.txt
set /p Error=<tmp.txt
echo %%a %Error% >> log.txt
)
```

The point is to create a list of usernames from a list of emails by querying an AD, which is not a problem. But I also want to send the errors to a log file, and something doesn't seem to be working when I send the temp.txt into the variable (I tried to add "echo %Error%" and all it says is "Echo is off"

Comment: can you post an example of `tmp.txt`?

Comment: Typically an error will look like this if the mail (%%a) is not found:
1st line: `dsget failed:'Target object for this command' is missing.`
2nd line: `type dsget /? for help.` 
If %%a exists tmp.txt will be empty

Comment: Are you sure, there is no first empty line?

Comment: If there is an error, there is no empty line. If there is no error, the file is empty (but it is rewritten on each instance of the loop)

Comment: I was falling into the same old trap again. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `%error%` in a block statement `for ... in (...) do (this is a block)`

A block is evaluated in one go, but you are changing the variable inside the block.
To get the changed variable, use delayed expansion:
At the start of your script write

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
```

and inside the block use the (changed) value with `!error!` instead of `%error%`

Changing

```
echo %%a %Error% >> log.txt
```

to

```
echo %%a !Error! >> log.txt
```

should solve your problem (together with the `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`).